# Issues with JQuery selector

Tags: jquery

I am creating a quiz, where a user can select either a true or false button. Everything seems to work fine when i break it down, except I cant get the logic correct on this line:

```
if ((correctAnswer == "t") && ($(this).hasClass('.true'+selectedAnswer))) {
```

correctAnswer is taken from a variable of the correct answers, and i want to compare that with if either the true of false button was pressed.

I've run this through jsfiddle and syntactically it is 'apparently' correct.

jsfiddle here ->  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teuzS/)

here's the full code:

```
        <style type="text/css">
        #c1,#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5,#c6,#c7,#next_area,.q_answer{ display: none; }
        #current_progress { 
            width: 43.2%;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){

            // if correct amount of answers, show the next button
            function checkAnswers() {
                if (correct === correct_answers) {
                    $("#next_area").fadeIn('slow');
                } else {
                    $("#next_area").fadeOut('slow');
                }
            }

            // vars to hold the total correct answers and the current running total
            var correct_answers = 1;
            var correct = 0;

            // correct answers to the questions
            var q1 = "f";
            var q2 = "f";
            var q3 = "f";
            var q4 = "t";
            var q5 = "f";
            var q6 = "f";
            var q7 = "f";


            // make question boxes act like a link to click
            $(".answer_box").mouseover(function() {
                $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
            });

            // function to check questions

            // listen for a click on any of the answer buttons
            $("#qs .answer_box").click(function() {

                //grab the id of the button clicked
                var selectedAnswer = $(this).attr('id');

                // grab the correct answer from var
                var correctAnswer = "q"+selectedAnswer;

                // if the correct answer is true and the true button was pressed
                if ((correctAnswer == "t") && ($(this).hasClass('.true'+selectedAnswer))) {

                    // check if false has already been selected
                    if ($(".false"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {

                        // if false selected, remove the class and make true active
                        $(".false"+selectedAnswer).removeClass("active");
                        $(".true"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                        correct++;
                        checkAnswers();                     

                    }

                         // if true has already been selected do nothing
                    else if ($(".true"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {


                    }
                    else {

                        // if neither true or false has been selected
                        $(".true"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                        correct++;
                        checkAnswers();                         

                    }

                  // if the correct answer is false and the true button was pressed
                } else if ((correctAnswer == "f") && ($(this).hasClass('.true'+selectedAnswer))) {

                    // check if false has already been selected
                    if ($(".false"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {

                        // if false selected, remove the class and make true active
                        $(".false"+selectedAnswer).removeClass("active");
                        $(".true"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                        correct--;
                        checkAnswers();                     

                    }

                         // if true has already been selected do nothing
                    else if ($(".true"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {


                    }
                    else {

                        // if neither true or false has been selected
                        $(".true"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                        correct--;
                        checkAnswers();                         

                    }               

                  // if the correct answer is false and the false button was pressed
                } else if ((correctAnswer == "f") && ($(this).hasClass('.false'+selectedAnswer))) {

                    // check if true has already been selected
                    if ($(".true"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {

                        // if false selected, remove the class and make true active
                        $(".true"+selectedAnswer).removeClass("active");
                        $(".false"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                        correct++;
                        checkAnswers();                     

                    }

                         // if false has already been selected do nothing
                    else if ($(".false"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {


                    }
                    else {

                        // if neither true or false has been selected
                        $(".false"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                        correct++;
                        checkAnswers();                         

                    }                       

                  // if the correct answer is true and the false button was pressed
                } else if ((correctAnswer == "t") && ($(this).hasClass('.false'+selectedAnswer))) {

                    // check if true has already been selected
                    if ($(".true"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {

                        // if false selected, remove the class and make true active
                        $(".true"+selectedAnswer).removeClass("active");
                        $(".false"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                        correct--;
                        checkAnswers();                     

                    }

                         // if false has already been selected do nothing
                    else if ($(".false"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {


                    }
                    else {

                        // if neither true or false has been selected
                        $(".false"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                        correct--;
                        checkAnswers();                         

                    }                   
                }                           
            });                     
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


        <div id="progress">
            <div id="progress_div">
                <div id="slide">
                    Complete [27/61]
                </div>
                <div id="progress_bar">
                    <div id="current_progress"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pagewidth">
            <div id="intro">
                <h1>Infection Control Training - Clinical Staff</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="head">
                <h2>Personal protective Equipment (PPE)</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <div id="q_direction">
                    <h3>Please answer the below question to proceed</h3>
                    <p class="txt italic marg_bot">You will not be able to proceed to the next page until you get the answers correct. If you get an answer wrong you can undo the incorrect answer marked with &quot;X&quot; by re-clicking and trying again with another answer.</p>
                </div>
                <h2 class="blue">Q: Gloves should routinely be worn for?</h2>
                <table id="qs">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tf_question_box">
                            Writing in notes 
                        </td>
                        <td class="answer_box true1" id="1">
                            True
                        </td>
                        <td class="answer_box false1" id="1">
                            False
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tf_question_box">
                            Answering the phone 
                        </td>
                        <td class="answer_box true2" id="2">
                            True
                        </td>
                        <td class="answer_box false2" id="2">
                            False
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tf_question_box">
                            Collecting linen 
                        </td>
                        <td class="answer_box true3" id="3">
                            True
                        </td>
                        <td class="answer_box false3" id="3">
                            False
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tf_question_box">
                            When there is a risk of contact with blood or body fluids
                        </td>
                        <td class="answer_box true4" id="4">
                            True
                        </td>
                        <td class="answer_box false4" id="4">
                            False
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tf_question_box">
                            Making beds
                        </td>
                        <td class="answer_box true5" id="5">
                            True
                        </td>
                        <td class="answer_box false5" id="5">
                            False
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tf_question_box">
                            Walking in the corridor 
                        </td>
                        <td class="answer_box true6" id="6">
                            True
                        </td>
                        <td class="answer_box false6" id="6">
                            False
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tf_question_box">
                            Giving out food and drinks 
                        </td>
                        <td class="answer_box true7" id="7">
                            True
                        </td>
                        <td class="answer_box false7" id="7">
                            False
                        </td>
                    </tr>                                                                                                                                       
                </table>
                <div id="next_area">
                    <p><span class="correct_txt">That's correct!</span> Click 'NEXT' to continue.</p>
                    <a href="page23.html"><img src="infectionControl_img/next_btn.png" onmouseover="this.src='infectionControl_img/next_btn_hvr.png'" onmouseout="this.src='infectionControl_img/next_btn.png'" id="next_btn"></a>
                </div>                  
            </div>
            <div id="imgs_plain">
                <img src="infectionControl_img/questions.jpg">
            </div>  
            <div id="footer">
            </div>          
        </div>
    </body>
```

Can you see why this is not working?

Comment: When you use hasClass you don't need to provide the .

Comment: i.e. hasClass('true'+selectedAnswer)

Comment: @ElliotLings You can edit comments instead of adding another one

Comment: @ElliotLings this should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I posted in a comment, you don't need to provide a . when using hasClass. i.e.

```
hasClass('true'+selectedAnswer)
```

instead of

```
hasClass('.true'+selectedAnswer)
```

Please try the following

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #c1,#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5,#c6,#c7,#next_area,.q_answer{ display: none; }
    #current_progress { 
        width: 43.2%;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        // if correct amount of answers, show the next button
        function checkAnswers() {
            if (correct === correct_answers) {
                $("#next_area").fadeIn('slow');
            } else {
                $("#next_area").fadeOut('slow');
            }
        }

        // vars to hold the total correct answers and the current running total
        var correct_answers = 1;
        var correct = 0;

        // correct answers to the questions            
        var answers = ["f", "f", "f", "t", "f", "f", "f"];


        // make question boxes act like a link to click
        $(".answer_box").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        });

        // function to check questions

        // listen for a click on any of the answer buttons
        $("#qs .answer_box").click(function() {

            //grab the id of the button clicked
            var selectedAnswer = $(this).attr('data-id');

            // grab the correct answer from var
            var correctAnswer = answers[selectedAnswer - 1];


            // if the correct answer is true and the true button was pressed
            if ((correctAnswer == "t") && ($(this).hasClass('true'+selectedAnswer))) {

                // check if false has already been selected
                if ($(".false"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {

                    // if false selected, remove the class and make true active
                    $(".false"+selectedAnswer).removeClass("active");
                    $(".true"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                    correct++;
                    checkAnswers();                     

                }

                     // if true has already been selected do nothing
                else if ($(".true"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {


                }
                else {

                    // if neither true or false has been selected
                    $(".true"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                    correct++;
                    checkAnswers();                         

                }

              // if the correct answer is false and the true button was pressed
            } else if ((correctAnswer == "f") && ($(this).hasClass('true'+selectedAnswer))) {

                // check if false has already been selected
                if ($(".false"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {

                    // if false selected, remove the class and make true active
                    $(".false"+selectedAnswer).removeClass("active");
                    $(".true"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                    correct--;
                    checkAnswers();                     

                }

                     // if true has already been selected do nothing
                else if ($(".true"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {


                }
                else {

                    // if neither true or false has been selected
                    $(".true"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                    correct--;
                    checkAnswers();                         

                }               

              // if the correct answer is false and the false button was pressed
            } else if ((correctAnswer == "f") && ($(this).hasClass('false'+selectedAnswer))) {

                // check if true has already been selected
                if ($(".true"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {

                    // if false selected, remove the class and make true active
                    $(".true"+selectedAnswer).removeClass("active");
                    $(".false"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                    correct++;
                    checkAnswers();                     

                }

                     // if false has already been selected do nothing
                else if ($(".false"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {


                }
                else {

                    // if neither true or false has been selected
                    $(".false"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                    correct++;
                    checkAnswers();                         

                }                       

              // if the correct answer is true and the false button was pressed
            } else if ((correctAnswer == "t") && ($(this).hasClass('false'+selectedAnswer))) {

                // check if true has already been selected
                if ($(".true"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {

                    // if false selected, remove the class and make true active
                    $(".true"+selectedAnswer).removeClass("active");
                    $(".false"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                    correct--;
                    checkAnswers();                     

                }

                     // if false has already been selected do nothing
                else if ($(".false"+selectedAnswer).hasClass('active')) {


                }
                else {

                    // if neither true or false has been selected
                    $(".false"+selectedAnswer).addClass("active"); 
                    correct--;
                    checkAnswers();                         

                }                   
            }                           
        });                     
    });
</script>
```

```
    <div id="progress">
        <div id="progress_div">
            <div id="slide">
                Complete [27/61]
            </div>
            <div id="progress_bar">
                <div id="current_progress"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pagewidth">
        <div id="intro">
            <h1>Infection Control Training - Clinical Staff</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="head">
            <h2>Personal protective Equipment (PPE)</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="q_direction">
                <h3>Please answer the below question to proceed</h3>
                <p class="txt italic marg_bot">You will not be able to proceed to the next page until you get the answers correct. If you get an answer wrong you can undo the incorrect answer marked with &quot;X&quot; by re-clicking and trying again with another answer.</p>
            </div>
            <h2 class="blue">Q: Gloves should routinely be worn for?</h2>
            <table id="qs">
                <tr>
                    <td class="tf_question_box">
                        Writing in notes 
                    </td>
                    <td class="answer_box true1" data-id="1">
                        True
                    </td>
                    <td class="answer_box false1" data-id="1">
                        False
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tf_question_box">
                        Answering the phone 
                    </td>
                    <td class="answer_box true2" data-id="2">
                        True
                    </td>
                    <td class="answer_box false2" data-id="2">
                        False
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tf_question_box">
                        Collecting linen 
                    </td>
                    <td class="answer_box true3" data-id="3">
                        True
                    </td>
                    <td class="answer_box false3" data-id="3">
                        False
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tf_question_box">
                        When there is a risk of contact with blood or body fluids
                    </td>
                    <td class="answer_box true4" data-id="4">
                        True
                    </td>
                    <td class="answer_box false4" data-id="4">
                        False
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tf_question_box">
                        Making beds
                    </td>
                    <td class="answer_box true5" data-id="5">
                        True
                    </td>
                    <td class="answer_box false5" data-id="5">
                        False
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tf_question_box">
                        Walking in the corridor 
                    </td>
                    <td class="answer_box true6" data-id="6">
                        True
                    </td>
                    <td class="answer_box false6" data-id="6">
                        False
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tf_question_box">
                        Giving out food and drinks 
                    </td>
                    <td class="answer_box true7" data-id="7">
                        True
                    </td>
                    <td class="answer_box false7" data-id="7">
                        False
                    </td>
                </tr>                                                                                                                                       
            </table>
            <div id="next_area">
                <p><span class="correct_txt">That's correct!</span> Click 'NEXT' to continue.</p>
                <a href="page23.html"><img src="infectionControl_img/next_btn.png" onmouseover="this.src='infectionControl_img/next_btn_hvr.png'" onmouseout="this.src='infectionControl_img/next_btn.png'" id="next_btn"></a>
            </div>                  
        </div>
        <div id="imgs_plain">
            <img src="infectionControl_img/questions.jpg">
        </div>  
        <div id="footer">
        </div>          
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I have changed as suggested above .true to true. but it still doesnt work?

Comment: @frobak The jsfiddle is blank

Comment: I know. I dont have an account and sign up is disabled due to spam. Can i save it without having an account?

Comment: @frobak You should also try avoiding using IDs of the same name as they need to be unique. You can use an attribute like data-id="7" instead of id="7".

Comment: Good stuff! When you're doing var correctAnswer = "q"+selectedAnswer; you were just creating a string, it wouldn't reference the variable :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `.true`to `true`

```
if ((eval(correctAnswer) == "t") && ($(this).hasClass('true'+selectedAnswer)))
```

Use the class name without `.` in front. See : http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

**Edit :**

Use eval()  to evaluates your dynamic variable.